# Removing unused properties and constructors from class decreases performance?

Tags: c#, benchmarking

I am creating a class where performance is critical. I am making changes and benchmarking as I make them to observe their effect.

The structure of the class is as follows:

```
class Example
{
    public int Property1 { get; private set; }
    public int Property2 { get; private set; }

    public Example()
        : this(0, 1, null)
    {
    }

    public Example(int param1, int param2)
        : this(param1, param2, null)
    {
    }

    public Example(int param1, int param2, Random param3)
    {
    }

    // Some other private fields...

    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
    public int DoWork()
    {
        // Do work...
        return 123;
    }
}
```

The structure of the test is as follows:

```
        Example e = new Example(123, 456, new Random());
        Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
        sw.Start();
        ulong n = 10000000000;
        for (ulong i = 1; i <= n; i++)
        {
            e.DoWork();
        }
        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine(sw.Elapsed);
```

During testing, I found that 'Property1', 'Property2' and all constructors bar the one called at the start of the test were not required - none of these were ever called or reference during the tests. The constructor called at the start of the test is called only once during the test.

So I updated the class declaration to:

```
class Example
{
    //public int Property1 { get; private set; }
    //public int Property2 { get; private set; }

    //public Example()
    //    : this(0, 1, null)
    //{
    //}

    //public Example(int param1, int param2)
    //    : this(param1, param2, null)
    //{
    //}

    // Some other private fields... (not removed).

    public Example(int param1, int param2, Random param3)
    {
    }

    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
    public int DoWork()
    {
        // Do work...
        return 123;
    }
}
```

Upon rerunning the test, I found that this actually decreases performance by a notable (relative to the testing) amount. My question is: what is causing this to happen, and is there anything I can do to alleviate it?

Comment: Have you [read this post](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/245802/20863) with some great answers surrounding `MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining`?

Comment: is your work purely CPU based, or does it use disk, network, etc? how often did you run the tests?

Comment: I'm guessing that because you removed those properties, you now need to calculate the value of them inside a local variable each time `DoWork` is called. This may be where the performance drop was, not necessarily that the constructor/property was removed, but there is additional work in "making up" the functionality of the properties locally. Without seeing the actual implementation of `DoWork` and the other changes you made to accommodate removing the properties, this is difficult to answer.

Comment: You could provide the performance difference and environment how you doing this benchmarking, are you using debug or release build? Dedicated cpu or are you running other stuff on that same cpu? Compare the disassemblies of release build using class with properties&constructors and class without them.